# Dart RegExp, How can I change the pattern?

Tags: regex, dart

This is example code

```dart
RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"(\w+)");
String str = "Parse my string";
Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(str);
```

What I want to do: Change the pattern after use

```dart
RegExp exp = RegExp(r"(\w+)");
String str = "Parse my string";
Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(str);

exp.pattern = r'^XXX';
```

How can i do like?

Comment: `exp = RegExp(r'^XXX');`

Comment: Is it correct and stable?

Comment: Why should it not be stable? You are just overwriting the variable with a new value. The old value will be automatically garbage collected if nothing else refer to it. But you do create a new `RegExp` object and need to call e.g. `exp.allMatches(str)` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the pattern of a `RegExp` after it has been created. Dart `RegExp` objects are immutable.

You can, as already commented, create a new and different `RegExp` and assign it to the `exp` variable: `exp = RegExp(r"^XXX");`. Or you can assign it to a different variable.

It's unclear what problem you are actually trying to solve.